# keep the memory of more than one index

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, each, devextreme

I have more than three TextBoxes. I want to send this data as in the code. The "indeks " value is always the last click. How do I keep the index?

```
      click:function(e) {

  var item = e.itemElement.index();
indeks = item;                   
 }
      var field= "";      
     onl: function () {
            $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache:true,
        url: MYURL,
        success: function (msg, result, status, xhr) {
            var obje = jQuery.parseJSON(msg)
            var i = 0;  
            field = " ";
            $('#wrapper *').filter(':input').each(function () {

                if (txtvalue != "") {
                    if (i) 
                        field += " and ";
                    field = field + "[" + obje[indeks]+ "]" $(this ).val() + "'";                      

                    i++;
                }

            });
                });

},
```

Comment: try to declare an array outside your success handler. then just push your indexes to this array in your success handler. this is a way to keep your clicked indexes.

Comment: thank you @bloC , Can you give an example pls

Comment: try something like https://jsfiddle.net/Lk2373h2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wasn't sure if I got your question right, I prefered to comment on your topic - but now it seems that my answer helped you, so I decided to post it as an actual answer:

1st step: declare an array outside your success handler
2nd step: push the index and the value for the element into this array
3rd step: loop through all entries of the array and build your 'select' statement

Here is your edited example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lk2373h2/1/

```
       var clickedIndexes = [];
    click:function(e) {

  var item = e.itemElement.index();
indeks = item;                   
 }
  var field= "";      
     onl: function () {
             $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache:true,
    url: MYURL,
    success: function (msg, result, status, xhr) {
        var obje = jQuery.parseJSON(msg)
        var i = 0;  
        field = " ";
        $('#wrapper *').filter(':input').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('id', i);
            var txtvalue=$(this).val();
              if (i) 
                            clickedIndexes.push({
                                index: indeks,
                                value: $(this ).val()
                            });
                        var selectString = "";

                        for (var u = 0; u < clickedIndexes.length; u++) {
                            selectString += "[" + obje[clickedIndexes[u].index].ALAN + "]" + "=" + "'" + clickedIndexes[u].value + "'";

                        }

                        field = selectString;  

                        i++;

        });
            });

},
```